# Div moving around center on mousemove()

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: I now have this: http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/115/ What if I want to get rid of container div and just use "document"? Is there a cleaner way to do this?**

I've been playing around with some code I have found online, and I almost have it where I want it. I just can't figure out how to accomplish the last part. In this JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/114/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      if (x <= 400) {
          x2=x*0.2
          $('div.box').css({'right': x2}); 
      }
       var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      if (y <= 400) {
           y2=y*0.2
          $('div.box').css({'bottom': y2}); 
      }
  });
});
```

What I want to do is have the "TEST BOX" Snap to the center of the containter DIV, and on mouse move, essentially "Orbit" the center. If you move your mouse in circles, you get the desired movement, but the box is at the wrong location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `.container` to the `<body>` and remove the container div.

Comment: What is the right location?  I am not understanding what it should look like.

Comment: @azeós what would that look like?

Comment: @SuperScript Look at the updated JS fiddle I posted. That is doing what it should, I'm just looking for a better way of doing it now.

Comment: If you what to get rid off the `.container` div, you could add that class to the `body` tag. You don't have it in your example, but you will in your final html... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/116/). But I don't know what else do you need.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/cGZxv/117/)?  If it is, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @SuperScript That is EXACTLY what I'm looking for! How can I have the square start in the center though? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JS for putting it in the body instead of a container.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX-window.innerWidth/2;
        if (x <= 400) {
            x2=x*0.2
            x3=x2+window.innerWidth/2
            $('div.box').css({'right': x3}); 
        }
        var y = e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2;
        if (y <= 400) {
            y2=y*0.2
            y3=y2+window.innerHeight/2
            $('div.box').css({'bottom': y3}); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then I changed the CSS to get it to start in the middle:

```
.box { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;bottom:50%;right:50%;}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/cGZxv/121/).

Comment: If I were to make the box larger, it isn't centered anymore. Any quick fix?